# TextBox underlining

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I put a textbox on the grid and it has default purple underlining when I click on it. How I can cancel it? I looked through all the properties, and nothing.

[image: Screenshot of textbox with purple line]

[image: Another image with a longer line]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverlow. You might have to share some XAML so that people can see how your textbox is defined and thus help you. The images on their own don't provide enough information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Material Design to me, you can change it in App.Xaml and then in the resource directory you should see this line:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml">
```

You can change the 'DeepPurple' to a different color Material Design supports.

Or you can get rid of it by using:

```
materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden"
```

so for example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

Hope this helps.